# How to work with columns in Slick 2 framework

Tags: scala, slick

I'm familiarizing with slick but I don't know how to deal with column values.

In the slick documentation they mention briefly the aggregate function exists, and I would like to use it in a query like this:

```
val e = Entity.filter(_.id === myid).exists
```

How do I deal with the result if I want to check if it's true? I would like to do pattern matching on it, or something like that.

```
e match{ 
  case true =>
  case false =>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `.run` to get the Boolean value:

```
val e: Boolean = Entity.filter(_.id === myId).exists.run
```

With `.run` you actually call the invoker, then you can if/else or param match.